# Are there any spin-off series or guest appearances planned for these Doctor Who characters?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of season 9,

> Clara and Me (Ashildir) left the Doctor with a brand new stolen TARDIS (in fact, not really a TARDIS 'cause the Doctor's granddaughter didn't name this particular one :D). Now, we have one immortal girl and a dead one, travelling through time and space.

So, are there any plans for them to come back in their own spin-off series, like Sarah-Jane did? Or are there plans for

> Clara

to become a recurring character?

I'm looking for official information which would support any rumors.

Comment: Nobody knows anything. We can wait to see a statement by Moffat maybe.

Comment: Right now all we could do for this question is speculate. I'm voting to close per our future works policy, it we ever find out we can reopen this and answer it.

Comment: @Saphirel: Our policy on questions that can't currently be answered is documented here: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: Shouldn't we hide the spoilers? The finale is not even 10 days old, and might not be shown yet in some countries...

Comment: @tilley31: plus not everyone watches everything immediately upon its release.

Comment: Whoops, sorry — I think I may have misunderstood the questions-about-future-works policy. Should I have left the wording of this question as-is, and left it closed until there’s a public statement that could be used as an answer?

Comment: I'm also voting to close. There is no way to answer this question from official information. Sorry!

Comment: I just wanted to know if any information filtered. Sorry guys, you can close this question :)